# Python: will a thread ever unblock while hanging on a `Queue.get(block=True)` call if the queue is suddenly destroyed from another thread/process?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, queue, python-multiprocessing

TLDR: Would a blocking get be unblocked by a queue that would be terminated in some way?

---

Long question:

Okay, so I know that the thread will hang if the queue (`multiprocessing.Queue`) remains empty forever while trying to fetch something from it with a blocking get.

But suppose now that in another thread or process, I close the queue with queue.close(), call queue.cancel_join_thread(), and then also queue.join_thread().

With the blocking "get" raise an exception or something upon trying to kill the queue like that?

Thanks!

Comment: I mean you have all the pieces why don't you test it out yourself, shouldn't take that long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an exception is raised if the queue is closed.

From the [latest documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues):

Under Queue.get() the following statement occurs:

"Changed in version 3.8: If the queue is closed, ValueError is raised instead of OSError."